# F# reload XmlProvider

Tags: xml, f#

I have a question, I was using Xml provider to load embedded content of xml, and it works great. But I was wondering is it possible to create dynamic XmlProvider.

For example I have an API that uploads xml file, so I read content of that file and i want to create XmlProvider based on that content (well now I can upload couple of types of xml schemes, for example events.xml and product.xml, so schemas can be dynamic).

I can prepare mechanics that will support those schemas but for that I need a XmlProvider, and as I see I need to have some sort of existing pattern for in a form of xml string or file path to xml file, for example:

```
type Test = XmlProvider<"<root><value>1</value><value>3</value></root>">
```

In my case I am unable to do that because I can upload several different xml files so far I have:

```
type Communication = XmlProvider<"<None></None>"> 
let ReadXmlFileUsingContent (xmlFileContent : string) = Provider.Parse xmlFileContent
```

But that wont work, because xml pattern is different then providers.

So my question is can I create provider with dynamic pattern or create provider when needed now when program starts up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to create an XmlProvider with a dynamic schema.  You'll have to peek into the XML to decide which XmlProvider you want to use:

```
open FSharp.Data
open System.Xml.Linq


type EventProvider = XmlProvider<"<event><foo id=\"10\" /></event>">
type ProductProvider = XmlProvider<"<product><bar name=\"bar\" /></product>">


type XmlResult =
| Event of EventProvider.Event
| Product of ProductProvider.Product
| Error of string


let parse xml = 
    try
        let doc = XDocument.Parse xml

        match doc.Root.Name.LocalName.ToLower() with
        | "event" -> Event (EventProvider.Parse xml)
        | "product" -> Product (ProductProvider.Parse xml)
        | other -> Error (sprintf "Unknown document root: %s" other)
    with
    | ex -> Error ex.Message
```